# modal popup on pageload with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I would like to know how to create a modal popup without using jquery or boostrap but using javscript. 
Modal popup should show only on page load for 30 sec and close automatically.
have tried using jquery and bootstrap but need to create in javascript

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.modal').modal('show');
      });
  </script>

 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; 
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Load Bootstrap modal on page launch</h4>
          </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>
           This is a simple Demo to launch a model on page load.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
           dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @varunagarwal have tried using bootstrap and jquery

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, whenever you perform any ui operations (such as Opening a modal, accessing dom nodes, etc etc), always wait for the document to be loaded. (The example is in 
Jquery but you can use vanilla js too).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 // Perform your operations here
});
```

Once you show the modal, you could setup a timeOut function `setTimeout(hideModal, 500)`
where

`hideModal` - The function which hides your modal

`500` - Timeout period after which you want to execute the function in `ms`

Answer (score 0):

Create  dom elements for modal and its background. Initially add a class `show` then use `setTimeout` to remove the class from classList after 3 secs

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementsByClassName('modalContainer')[0].classList.remove('show');
}, 3000)
```

```css
.mainContainer,
.modalContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center
}

.modalContainer {
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}

.modal {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 15;
  background: red;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='mainContainer'>
  <div class='modalContainer show'>
    <div class='modal'>Here is the modal</div>
  </div>

</div>
```